# 2007: How do I edit the search results page? I don't have an Edit Page option

Tags: search

I'm trying to use the tutorial [here](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/03/15/moss-2007-customize-the-search-result-using-xslt.aspx) to edit the search results page for a particular site (not a root site). According to the tutorial, there's supposed to be an "Edit Page" link under Site Actions when viewing the search results page. I don't have that. I've got Create Page & Create Site, but no Edit Page. The site is not locked, and I can make other changes to the site, such as creating pages and adding/editing list items.

I am one of the two farm admins - though I'm more of a developer than an admin - so I assume it's not a permissions issue. What am I missing?

Comment: what's the url of search result page?

Comment: If the URL of the search results page starts /_layouts, then you are using a page that lives in the SharePointRoot, and not a search site. This page cannot be edited in this manner.

Comment: Ah poo. It's at http:/ /rootsite/site/_layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are not using Search Center to display the search results. _layouts/OSSSearchResults.aspx  is an application page and it is not designed to be edited.

You need to provision a Search center site and configure your site collection to use the search center's result page. The you can customize the search results page because it will be served from Pages library as opposed to _layouts.